# Cross platform (Windows, OSX 10.6) OpenGL development in Scheme

Tags: opengl, scheme

Looking for a version of scheme that will allow me to develop OpenGL applications that run on Windows and Mac OSX.

I have tried Spark-Scheme and can't get it to compile on my Mac using OSX 10.6, Chicken scheme gives gcc errors whilst trying to use chicken-install OpenGL.

Has anyone had any success with cross platform OpenGL development using Scheme, if Yes would you care to tell me your secret.

Comment: Racket is cross-platform and comes with OpenGL demos you can load and run located under <install dir>/collects/sgl/examples/gears|gl-alpha

Answer (score 3):

Try [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) (nee plt-scheme)  It has open-gl libraries that run on Windows, OS-X and Linux.

Comment: I'm not sure, it used to, I have not tried it.  It has an extensive FFI for interfacing to C.

See file:///usr/plt/doc/raco/index.html for the tools that might do this.

Comment: @driveby, it has a JIT (an interface to Gnu Lightning). However, Racket is a fantastic cross-platform development environment for graphical applications.